# What is wrong with this validator in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, validation

I am trying to put a validator in my page that checks the value of a textbox and prints the error message if the value of the textbox is not a number of length 3. Here it is:

```
 <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" 
        ControlToValidate="tCourse" ErrorMessage="Enter a number of length 3!" 
        ForeColor="Red" ValidationExpression="^[0-9]]{3}$"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

The problem is, even though i enter a number like "432" into the box, it still gives the error message. What is wrong here can anyone see?

Thanks

Comment: How about adding a property of `maxlength="3"` into the textbox instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your RegEx has an extra "]" in it:

```
^[0-9]]{3}$
```

Should be:

```
^[0-9]{3}$
```

If you're curious, your current regex should match "4]]]" as a valid entry

Answer (score 1):

You have `^[0-9]]{3}$` there is a double closing `]`, try `^[0-9]{3}$`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

`ValidationExpression="\d{3}"`